# How can I downgrade rails from rails 6 to 5.2.3 on WINDOWS 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Need to downgrade from the newest rails to rails 5.2.3 on WINDOWS 10 but I have no clue how to do it. Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to downgrade an existing application or just trying to use a different version to generate a new application? The first one will be horribly painful when crossing major releases e.g. 6.0 -> 5.X (upgrading is difficult enough). If you are looking for the second then you just `gem install rails -v 5.2.3` and then run `rails _5.2.3_ new app_name_here`

Comment: As another aside if you are running Windows 10 and not using WSL you should really look into it. It will make your development experience much more natural and far easier

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages. We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, what steps did you take and what happened? Without evidence of any effort of searching for a solution or trying anything, it looks like you want us to find tutorials for you, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall Rails using:

```
gem uninstall rails
```

and

```
gem uninstall railties
```

Select your Rails version for each of these commands and it should remove them.

Then, install Rails version 5.2.3 by running:

```
gem install rails -v 5.2.3
```